# issues with passing command line args to custom training job vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, custom-training

I am trying to run basic custom training job

```
job = aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJob(
 display_name='testjob-name',
 container_uri='gcr.io/prj-id/image-name:latest',
 project=project_id,
 credentials= credentials,
 staging_bucket= 'stage-bucket'
)
```

using below code to run the job

```
job.run(
        args=['--data_dir', '/gcs/bucket/folder',
        '--model_dir', '/gcs/bucket/model',
        '--configs', 'internal-config.yml'],
        replica_count=1,
        sync=True
    )
```

Training job is getting exited with code 127 when I am passing args with job.run(). kindly help, what is the correct way to send command line arguments to custom training python script.
There isn’t much coming up in logs either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you run custom job following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job#create)? Also can you share the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/migration/UJ3%20Vertex%20SDK%20Custom%20Image%20Classification%20with%20custom%20training%20container.ipynb) you have to join arguments and their values

```
job.run(
        args=['--data_dir=/gcs/bucket/folder',
        '--model_dir=/gcs/bucket/model',
        '--configs=internal-config.yml'],
        replica_count=1,
        sync=True
    )
```